# FOSUserBundle : config error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

i m using FOSUserBundle i also follow the documentation but i m getting an error

> FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot import resource "C:\wamp\www\sym\app/config\config.yml" from "C:\wamp\www\sym\app/config/config_dev.yml".
>    Not getting whats the error.

**`app/routing.yml`**

```
# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#   resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#   prefix:   /_internal
_user_bundle:
    resources:"@AcmeUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /
```

**`app/config.yml`**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    charset:         UTF-8
    router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'] } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        auto_start:     true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    # java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        # closure:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/compiler.jar
        # yui_css:
        #     jar: %kernel.root_dir%/java/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%

jms_security_extra:
    secure_controllers:  true
    secure_all_services: false

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

**`app/config_dev.yml`**

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: false
```

Comment: Does `C:\wamp\www\sym\app/config\config.yml` really exist?

Comment: Also, I don't think it has anything to do with FOSUserBundle. Does it throw the same error even if you remove its routing?

Comment: yes..if i remove routing than also it gives me error..

Comment: i think the error may be becoz of fos_user in the config.yml.

Answer (score 0):

You might have included tab in your config.yml or config_dev.yml file. You do not include tab for yml files. You can use space instead of tab. Hope it will help you.

Comment: i check but i didnt see any tab in routing,config or security.than also it is giving me the same error along with it one more it is show    InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "fos_user" (in C:\wamp\www\sym\app/config\config.yml). Looked for namespace "fos_user", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "doctrine", "assetic", "sensio_framework_extra", "jms_security_extra", "acme_demo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution"